# Ubuntu cant login tmp deleted

Tags: ubuntu, login

I deleted tmp folder and now I can't login. Not even with root!

I tryed with safe mode and it's not doing anything, just showing me a black screen.

When i press Ctr+Alt+F1 is asking me to login but its says all time 'Login incorect'.

What should I do?

I use the Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS. Please help me, Thanks!

I changed my display now I can enter in recovery mode but when I try to change envy thing in system gives me error. Ex. on changing password: Authentification token mainipulation error. password unchanged

Comment: Try entering in recovery mode, remount the partition as read-wrte and change your password

Comment: I can't it shows me a black screen

Comment: Ok. Try using an ubuntu installation CD. Boot from there, and then, you can operate as root

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you see a black screen then Ubuntu dosent recognize you're monitor. Change it.

Restart and hold shift.

Goto recovery mode.

Select network and press ok.

Select root and press ok.

Type:

```
  rm /tmp

  Mkdir /tmp

 Chmod 1777 /tmp
```

Answer (score 0):

First, download an [ubuntu iso](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/GettingUbuntu) and burn it to a CD.

Boot the Ubuntu Live CD.
Press `Ctrl-Alt-F1`

```
# mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
```

If you created a custom partition layout when installing Ubuntu you have to find your root partition using the fdisk utility. See the section Finding your root partition.

```
# chroot /mnt
```

**EDIT:** (@Flup 's correction)

then, do

```
mkdir /tmp && chmod 1777 /tmp
```

Note: In the mount command, `/dev/sda1` will need to be replaced with the partition where the root of the file system resides.

If you need more info, please refer to : https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCdRecovery

Comment: This is a good answer, but he needs to recreate `/tmp`, not reset a password.  After the `chroot`, do `mkdir /tmp && chmod 1777 /tmp`, then try rebooting.

Comment: Thanks! Do you mind if I put that on my answer?

Comment: Feel free, just stick the royalties cheque in the post ;-)

Comment: The `chroot` isn't needed, and just adds unnecessary complication. It's easy to create a `/mnt/tmp` without it.

Comment: I change my display and now I can enter in recovery mode. Better solution?

Comment: I didn't knew that the deletion of /tmp is related to the display.